# Pinescript bar color 1 bar back for specific condition

Tags: pine-script

So lets say you have a couple conditions defining bar color for each bar in a Pinescript. Now one condition shall change bar color one bar back, so with an offset. Is this possible allowed in Pinescript? Or does it have to be one bar color series per script and only that in full could be shifted via offset?

Tried two separate barcolor calls, to differentiate for the one with offset and one without, but that did not work well.

Thanks any input.